# HTML Textbox display tooltip value as the same as text box value whichever keys enter

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a HTML Text Box, 

Whenever I type text to this text box, 
I want to show this same text as a Tool tip. 
Is there any way to make it like that by using JQUERY. If so please let me know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
$(".ttip").hide();
$("input").keyup(
function(){
    var one=$(this).val();
    $(".ttip").fadeIn().text(one);
    }
);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hUAXc/

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like that?

```
$('.textbox').keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSfdH/).